# How to search multiple tags in a Socrata site?

Tags: socrata

You can find all datasets in a socrata site like this:

```
/data/?tags=parking
```

How can you find datasets that match one of several tags (`OR`)? This doesn't work:

```
/data/?tags=parking&tags=footpaths
```

Comment: what url do you see this on? cannot reproduce on nyc open data. https://nycopendata.socrata.com/data/&tags=parking 404s

Comment: nasa doesn't follow this convention either, so you probably want to edit the question as well https://data.nasa.gov/data?category=&search=tags&type=maps

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake, should be `?tags=`. For instance https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/data?tags=parking

Answer (score 2):

This undocumented method seems to get really close:

```
/data?search=tags%3Aparking+OR+tags%3Afootpath
```

That is, you can search for "tags:parking OR tags:footpath". It's "close" because Socrata applies stemming, so it also finds datasets with tags such as "park", but it ranks exact matches higher.

It seems that Socrata has removed boolean queries from more recent deployments, however.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing tags are comma separated, because [This search returns results with parking and sensors tags: https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/data?tags=parking,sensors](https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/data?tags=parking,sensors)
Didn't use your example, because there is only one set tagged with footpaths, and it doesn't also have a parking tag.

EDIT: comma separated doesn't do SQL's `OR`, but adding `&OR` between tag declarations seems to work, like so https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/data?tags=parking&OR&tags=sensors

EDIT Two:
this solution shows only sets matching all requirements, not all sets with one requirement. solution provided by @Steve Bennett is the desired `OR` solution.

Comment: Ok, it's good to know that you can do an AND query with a comma. I'm looking for an OR query though.

Comment: not sure how i missed that....my bad

Comment: That `&OR&` method doesn't seem to work. There are 7 datasets tagged "parking", so combining that with sensors should yield more than that. This works better: https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/data?search=tags%3Aparking+OR+tags%3A%22pedestrian+sensors%22

Comment: ha, i completely misread the SQL OR statement definition, apologies

Answer (score 1):

No need to use the secret parameters on our `/data.json` feed, you can actually use our actually-not-secret Discovery API now!: http://docs.socratadiscovery.apiary.io/#reference/0/searching-particular-categoriestags/category/tag-search-api

Edit: I now understand better what you're looking for. I thought you were looking for an API, but it really looks like you're just looking for options for our data catalog interface.

The `tags` parameter can be repeated on that page to `AND` together multiple tags. Does that do the job?

https://data.seattle.gov/browse?tags=crime&tags=police%20report

Comment: any documentation for said secret parameters?

Comment: Hmm, that's just the API though. In this instance I'm looking for a publicly shareable URL that would resolve to a human-readable search results page. So not so useful in this particular case.

Comment: @albert I'd recommend you use the Discovery API instead. It's got more search options and is officially supported

Comment: so yes there is documentation its just internal and you don't want word to get out?

Comment: @albert The way the `/browse` or `/data` catalogs can be filtered is dependent on how that particular customer's site is configured. But they're powered by the Discovery API, so I'd start there to get an idea how they work, or just use the Discovery API directly.